# How do i get Activity instead of FragmentActivty?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

getActivity (kotlin: activity) inside a fragment gives me FragmentActivity. But now i need Activity instead of FragmentActivity for a specific listener and its not possible to cast it to Activity.

Comment: every `FragmentActivity` is `Activity` same as every engineer is a human.

Comment: but my firebase listener for registering throws an error if i pass FragmentActivity instead of activity

Comment: nobody knows what you are doing, and what you are using. You should have mentioned it in question, as well as **which error it is throwing**

Comment: sorry guys. the error was connected to the kotlin null safe operator not the wrong type.  Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Activity was expected

Answer (score 7):

for any one else may have this problem.
just add !!
**(activity!!)**

Comment: Just tried this and was advised to use requireActivity() now by Android Studio

Answer (score 4):

The `FragmentActivity` class extends the `Activity` class.

So if anything requires an `Activity`, you can always simply pass in a reference to a `FragmentActivity`.

If your code still does not work, then this is not the issue. If so, you'll need to post some more information for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity)
```

or

```
requireActivity()   //to getActivity
requireContext()    //to getContext
```

Comment: According to the IDE this should be resolved like said with requireActivity()

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you pass `FragmentActivity` but not `FragmentActivity?` or make it optional in parameters. I will explain why, and here is an example:

```
// call somewhere in Fragment
 myFunc(activity)
```

**Method:**

```
fun myFunc(activity: Activity?) {
    // doing smth
}
```

We set `Activity?` as optional because fragment class is Java class, and Kotlin assumes that it might be null (fragment keeps ref to the activity as nullable). So that's why you have the `Type mismatch` exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
activity as Activity
```

or

```
activity!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `requireActivity()`.

As Moonbloom points out `FragmentActivity` *is* an `Activity`.

If you look carefully at your error you'll see that the problem is that your passing `FragmentActivity?` when the function requires a **not null** `Activity`.